# Create Dataframe with a certain number of columns

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

I have the following Dataframe:

[image: Excert Dataframe]

Now i want to copy the column "Power" as often as i want to another column in the same Dataframe.
The column names should be: Power_1; Power_2; Power_3.....

Creating the Dataframe is too complicated to share, but a simple example how to add the columns with a while-loop would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in range(10):
    df[f"Power_{i}"] = df["Power"]
```